# How to rename local files on machine in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I am trying to rename 90 PDF files on my machine to a specific format.

**My current files are named as such:**

```
file_name 
(P102180.R2858.M60102148)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF
(P10424.R2858.M60010424)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF
(P14479.R2858.M60004820)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF
(P14479.R2858.M60031167)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF
(P14479.R2858.M60032342)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF
```

**I was able to extract a column I need to rename the files as such:**

```
 file_name                                                            MVNDR_NBR
(P102180.R2858.M60102148)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF               60102148
(P10424.R2858.M60010424)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF                60010424
(P14479.R2858.M60004820)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF                60004820
(P14479.R2858.M60031167)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF                60031167
(P14479.R2858.M60032342)SupplierPerformanceDashboard.PDF                60032342
```

**I then did a join and concatenation and now my table looks as such**
[image]

How can I make `new_file_name` replace the `old file_names` locally on my machine

Answer (score 0):

We may use `file.rename` (assuming these files are in the working directory)

```
file.rename(df1$file_name, df1$new_file_name)
```

Comment: I got false for all my values

Comment: @Jaskeil As I mentioned in the post, you may need the directory path as well, which you haven't showed in thepost

Comment: @Jaskeil can you show the path where the files are located?

Answer (score 0):

First,you should make sure the current working directory is the path your PDF files exists.(You can use '**dir()**' or '**list.files()**' to check).Then you can rename these files using the script:

```
    files <- list.files()
    n <- 1
    for (f in files)
    {
       newname <- df$new_file_name[n]
       file.rename(f,newname)
       n+=1           
    }
```

Be carefule the newname is corresponding to the original file name!